# Get the internal URI storage location (gs://) after uploading data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Reading the Firebase documentation, once I have uploaded an image data to Firebase storage bucket (using `putData()` ), I can get a download URL by calling the `downloadURL()` method from a `StorageReference` instance.

And so I did :

```
uploadRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("failed to download url")
    } else {
        let stringURL = url!.absoluteString
        downloadURLCompletion(stringURL)
    }
}
```

`stringURL` returns a public URL starting with https://firebasestorage.googleap...

But what I want to get and store in my Firebase database is the internal URI starting with gs://

Is there a way to request it from Firebase IOS SDK ? Firebase UI seems to provide it automaticaly,  but I'm not using Firebase UI.

I know that I can generate this URI by using this template :

```
gs://<bucket_name>/<file_path_inside_bucket>
```

...but it assumes that I should hard-code the name of my bucket which doesn't make me happy...

Comment: `uploadRef.description` will give you the `gs://` URL.
You may need to add the file you've just uploaded (name + extension, e.g,: `fileName.jpg`) at the end of it (depends on where `uploadRef` is pointing to).